# randomly set a variable from 3 values - javascript

Tags: javascript

I hav the following which sets the stepSize variable to a random number between 1 and 30:

```
this.stepSize = random(1,30) ;
```

I would like to set another variable (this.color) to a random value between 3 options:

```
this.color
#f7f2ea,  #f4f4f4 , #ede0ce
```

How could I do this?

Comment: use an array containing these 3 values, rand an index between 0 and the array length -1; and get the element pointing to this random index.

Answer (score 3):

put the color you want in an array and then random the index

```
var index= Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
var colorArray = ["f7f2ea","f4f4f4","ede0ce"];

this.color = colorArray[index];
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach

```
function randomChoice() {
    return arguments[Math.random() * arguments.length | 0];
}

this.color = '#' + randomChoice('f7f2ea', 'f4f4f4', 'ede0ce');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
this.color = ["#f7f2ea",  "#f4f4f4" , "#ede0ce"];
var randValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
console.log(this.color[randValue])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

if(rand==0)
    this.color = "f7f2ea";
else if(rand==1)
    this.color = "f4f4f4";
else if(rand==2)
    this.color = "ede0ce";
```

Comment: This will throw _Reference Errors_, I think you want _String_

Comment: `this.color = rand == 2 ? "ede0ce" :
                 rand == 1 ? "f4f4f4" :
                             "f7f2ea";` Precise and does the same thing.

Comment: Newlines can be inserted to make it readable. StackOverflow doesn't allow newlines in comments.